# rendering view on ajax response in cakephp 3

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm working in CakePHP 3.4

I'm making an Ajax request to controller for fetching some data from database and response it back to the view. Since, the data returned is a set of data which can be from 1 row to 100 rows. I want to make a separate view and send response data to that view and then replace div content with that view.

This is how ajax call is being made

```
$('#trigger_connect_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {server_id : $('#server_id').val()};
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: data,
        url: '/servers/trigger-connect',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
});
```

and `triggerConnect()` action

```
public function triggerConnect()
{
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $id = $this->request->getData('server_id');

    $server = $this->UserServers->get($id);
    $ftp = new \FtpClient\FtpClient();
    $ftp->connect($server->server_url);

    $res = $ftp->login($server->server_username, $server->server_password);

    if ($res) {
        $response['code'] = 100;
        $response['type'] = 'Success';
        $response['message'] = 'Login Success';
        $response['content'] = $ftp->scanDir();
    } else {
        $response['code'] = 101;
        $response['type'] = 'Error';
        $response['message'] = 'Login Failed';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

current view file has

```
<div id="response-content"></div>
```

This is working fine and returned content is printing in console. I know, I can iterate through data and print in view using jQuery but I want to create a separate view file for it which will render the returned data and then update a div in current view file with rendered view.

Comment: Offtopic: Controller actions should **never echo data**! **http://stackoverflow.com/a/42819969/1392379**

Comment: Thanks ndm, that's my mistake. I'll take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is jquery [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method for you if you want to load particular CakePHP method with it's view file.

```
$('#trigger_connect_btn').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $("#response-content").load("/servers/trigger-connect", {
       server_id : $("#server_id").val()
   });
});
```

The above script will load the corresponding view of function `trigger-connect` to `#response-content`.

And now comment out / delete the following line in your action , and make sure you have set variable to iterate that in your corresponding view just as you need.

```
// $this->autoRender = false;
```