# Cakephp - How to return array content with array name

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want return the json data from my controller.
I have written belo code.

```
$this->loadModel('Users');
$query = $this->Users->find();
$users = $query->select(['id', 'name']);
echo json_encode($users);
```

This return data in below format:
[{"id":1,"news_type":1,"name":"hoge"},{"id":2,"news_type":1,"name":"hoge1"}]

but I want it in below format:
{"categories":[{"id":1,"news_type":1,"name":"hoge"},{"id":2,"news_type":1,"name":"hoge1"}]}

Comment: Do not echo data from controllers, that's not how controllers are supposed to behave! **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable**

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

I have used this:

```
echo json_encode(array("users" => $users));
```