# CakePHP 3.6.14: Autocomplete field with search in multiple columns in database table

Tags: php, jquery, search, cakephp, autocomplete

I am struggling to create a form with an autocomplete field (`Customer`). So when the user types some letters in this field then the running query will return all customers which contain these letters in the `name`, `surname` or `company` fields and the user can select one to complete the form.

This is the form field for the customer:

**add.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->control('customer', ['id' => 'Autocomplete', 'empty' => true]);
```

This is the Js function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // Caching the movieName textbox:
            var company = $('#Autocomplete');

            // Defining a placeholder text:
            company.defaultText('Search for customers');

            // Using jQuery UI's autocomplete widget:
            company.autocomplete({
                minLength    : 1,
                source        : 'getAll',
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   $(company).val(ui.item.id);
               },
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function( data ) {
                response( data );
            }
            });

        });

        // A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

        $.fn.defaultText = function(value){

            var element = this.eq(0);
            element.data('defaultText',value);

            element.focus(function(){
                if(element.val() == value){ 
                    element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
                }
                }).blur(function(){ 
                if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){ 
                    element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
                }
            });

            return element.blur();
        }
</script>
```

**Controller.php**

This is the getAll function which contains the query:

```
public function getAll() {


        $this->autoLayout = false;
        $this->autoRender = false;


        $results = TableRegistry::get('Customers')->find('all', ['fields' => ['company', 'name', 'surname'], 
            'conditions' => [
                    'name LIKE' => '%'.$this->request->query('term').'%',
                    'company LIKE' => '%'.$this->request->query('term').'%',
                    'surname LIKE' => '%'.$this->request->query('term').'%',
            ]]);
        $response = array();
        $i = 0;
        foreach($results as $result){
           $response[$i] = $result['company'];

            $i++;

        }

       echo json_encode($response);

}
```

But I don't get any results...

Comment: As a general note, **[controllers should not echo data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable/42379581#42379581)**!

Comment: As ndm states, you need to return your data instead of doing an echo