# CakePHP 3.6: json_encode maximum depth reached

Tags: php, json, ajax, cakephp

I have an ajax request in my application which returns a json object:

```
public function getCustomerTransactions($customerid = null)
    {
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout(false);
        $this->autoRender = false;

        $selectedCustomerCompany = $this->request->getData('customer');
        $selectedCustomer = TableRegistry::get('Customers')->find('all', [
                            'conditions' => ['Customers.company LIKE '=> $selectedCustomerCompany]
                        ])->first();

        $customerTransactions = TableRegistry::get('Transactions')->find('all', [
                            'conditions' => ['customer_id '=> $selectedCustomer->id, 'transaction_type_id ' => 1, 'invoice_id IS NULL']//,

                        ]);

        echo json_encode($customerTransactions);
    }
```

But instead of 19 `transactions` it returns 11 and then this message (I can see it from network tab) :

> **Warning** (512): Unable to emit headers. Headers sent in
>   file=/var/www/vhosts/domain/public_html/demo/app/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php line=508 [**CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php**, line
>   **48**]Code Context
>   
>   `0000BB">            
>   
>   style="color: #007700">if (
>   
>   0000BB">Configure::read
>   
>   007700">('debug')) {`
>
> class="code-highlight">
>   
>   `0000BB">                trigger_error
>   
>   style="color: #007700">(
>   
>   0000BB">$message, E_USER_WARNING);`             
>   
>   `style="color:
>   
>   007700">} else {`
>
> none;">$response = object(Cake\Http\Response) {
>
> 'status' => (int) 200,   'contentType' =>
>   'text/html',    'headers' => [
>         'Content-Type' => [            [maximum depth reached]         ]   ],
>     'file' => null,    'fileRange' => [],
>     'cookies' => object(Cake\Http\Cookie\CookieCollection)
>   {},   'cacheDirectives' => [],   'body' =>
>   ''
>
> } $maxBufferLength = (int) 8192 $file =
>   '/var/www/vhosts/domain/public_html/demo/app/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php'
>   $line = (int) 508 $message = 'Unable to emit headers. Headers
>   sent in
>   file=/var/www/vhosts/domain/public_html/demo/app/src/Controller/InvoicesController.php line=508'Cake\Http\ResponseEmitter::emit() -
>   CORE/src/Http/ResponseEmitter.php, line 48 Cake\Http\Server::emit() -
>   CORE/src/Http/Server.php, line 141

So I get this javascript error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 6922

Because there is html code in the response.

I tried to set the depth option in `json_encode` but I get the same results.

**UPDATE**

I ended up using:

```
if($this->request->is('ajax')){
            Configure::write('debug', 0);
        }
```

In the controller. But is this the correct way?

Comment: Alternately, you could figure out why a debug message is being created and fix that problem.

Comment: @GregSchmidt I know thats why I didn't asnwer my question. I can't find out why this debug message is created after a number of query results. I guess that depth has nothing to do with the number of the elements of the returned array but with the depth of the returned array. For example [a, b, [1, 2, 3]] has depth 2 while [1, 2, 3, ......... 10000] has depth 1

Comment: "_[maximum depth reached]_" is not an error, it's just a notice from the debugger that it won't inspect the (context) data further, as its maximum depth limit (defaults to `3`) has been reached (this is to avoid possible performance problems). Your problem is that you are echoing data in a controller, that's a no-go, controllers should never echo data! **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable**