# CakePHP 4 : Simple JSON view return

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am new in cakephp, 
I am trying to develop a simple REST BREAD (BROWSE, READ, EDIT, ADD, DELETE) using cakephp version 4.
After installed I created a simple controller called UsersController with method `index,view,edit,delete`. Not created any model and templates yet.

For Browse json, in Users/index method I have used code like

```
public function index()
{
          $users = $this->Users->find('all');
          echo json_encode($users);
          exit;
}
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "jone",
    "created": "2020-01-22T00:00:00+00:00",
    "modified": "2020-01-22T00:00:00+00:00"
  }
]
```

Questions :

1) Without using exit how I will prevent controller to render `not found template error exception` ?

2) How I will change http response code using cake asset. example `200 ok will be 2000 ok.` ?

3) Without use json_encode , am I able to return a json view using cakephp asset, if yes then how ?

Comment: If I don't want to use .json extension, how can I handle ?

Comment: Check the Cookbook https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#creating-json-views4

Comment: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable/42379581#42379581**