# I want to get order nos from the id which I'm providing via ajax function but not showing the values in success: function(response)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0

This is my .ctp file ajax function =>
this is  my ajax function in which I'm assigning the id so that I can get all the order nos for this particular id and append it to the select option.

```
function getOrderNum(id){
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url: "/CustomerProblems/getOrders",                  
                data:"id="+id,
                // dataType:"json",
                success:function(response){
                    // $(".order").html("<option value="+response+">"+response+"</option>");                    
                    alert(response);
                    // console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

This is my controller =>
Here I'm providing the id via the ajax function but not getting the response properly on ajax response

```
public function getOrders($id){
        $this->render(false);
        if($this->request->is('get')){
            $order_no = $this->CustomerProblems->Orders->find('all')->where(['Orders.customer_id'=>$id])->extract('order_no');
            $this->set("order_no", $order_no);    
            // pr($customers->toArray());die;
            echo json_encode($customers);
            // echo $customers;
            // die;
        }
    }
```

Comment: First things first, **do not echo data in controllers!** **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378793/how-to-output-custom-http-body-contents-with-cakephp-3-4-echoing-causes-unable/42379581#42379581** Fix that, and then do some debugging, start with inspecting your browser's network console to figure what exactly your request _does_ receive in return. Also check your log files for possible errors.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using get method you can try passing object parameter in the data and also try to set the content-type

```js
function getOrderNum(id){
            $.ajax({
                type:"get",
                url: "/CustomerProblems/getOrders",                  
                data:JSON.stringify({id:id}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success:function(response){
                    // $(".order").html("<option value="+response+">"+response+"</option>");                    
                    alert(response);
                    // console.log(response);
                }
            });
  }
```

Comment: Can't access the variable name which I sent from the ajax query. I've used many method to fetch the value from variable it doesn't get the value.